# How to start Azure Storage Emulator in VS2017 agent in VSTS using YAML configuration file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

In my azure-pipelines.yml file, I have this task:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

In my integration tests I use both MSQLLocalDB (that seems to work fine) and AzureStorageEmulator (that doesn't).

I would like to try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51726177/182172).

How can I add these commands:

```
sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB
sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB
sqllocaldb info MSSQLLocalDB

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" start
```

to run before the test task to have a running instance of Azure Storage Emulator before the tests start?

Comment: Put the script in a `powershell` script task and try it

Comment: Have you being able to fix this somehow ? I am on same issue :(

Comment: Couldn’t. I had to use a real azure storage account.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- script: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe" create "v13.0" 13.0 -s'
  displayName: 'Init Test Db'

- script: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" start'
  displayName: 'Start Storage Emulator'
```

Needs to be on a `vs2017-win2016` vmImage.