# Automated integration tests of Azure Service integrations in Azure DevOps CI

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I have a project written on Java within Azure DevOps.

I have some integrations, like Postgresql DB, CosmosDB, Storage Queue, Storage Blob. There are some emulators for these Azure service, which I can use for integration testing on my local machine **during development**.

What about **CI?** Are there practices/tools for such tests?

*For example, GitLab provides (they call them) Services which are Docker containers with some applications, like relational databases, inside:* https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/postgres.html

Answer (score 1):

You can now setup a CI/CD pipeline with Cosmos DB, you need to add the [Cosmos DB Emulator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=azure-cosmosdb.emulator-public-preview) extension to your Azure DevOps account for free.

You can later on use it in a Build Definition as an additional Task, it will expose an Endpoint you can connect to (the Account Key is the same as the Local Emulator).

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-setup-ci-cd

Comment: is there a chance for other Services?

Comment: Not that I'm aware at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

For some of these, Microsoft provides an [Azure Storage Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator). This isn't running on the Hosted Build Agents, although there seem to be some [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723795/vso-hosted-build-controller-is-the-azure-storage-emulator-supported).